# vtiger crm development setup

Tags: vtiger

The problem is that the source code distribution is not exactly the code that runs after installation. The installer, which runs when the site is accessed for the first time, generates a lot of code. Also, a running system stores some data in php source code (e.g. user profiles - under the */user_privileges* directory) rather than in the database. So, I have the following unsatisfactory possibilities.

(1) Put the original source code under VC and edit it. In this case I have to do a fresh install and run the installer every time to see how my changes are working.

(2) Put the installed source code (after the installer has run) under VC, and edit it. In this case I have immediate feedback, but I can't use that code for new installations. I also have to exclude everything that the running system writes in the source tree from the VC.

Any suggestions?
I am working with Vtiger CRM version 6.0Beta, but any tips relevant to version 5 would help.
Thanks.

Comment: CRMs has a totally complex role/permission structures. Setting and getting this permissions from DB is a nightmare, while file access is really faster. I'm sure your developments has no relation to /user_privileges directory.

Comment: @HPM, I can think of 2 possible solutions: 
(1) Put original code under VC excluding variable objects, commit original, run install, commit. In the end - patch original source.
(2) Unpack original source outside docroot, move runtime directories and symlink remaining parts (under VC) to docroot.
May be there is a better way? 
(Unfortunately, my development is related to user accounts.)

Comment: Unfortunately I have not a good knowledge about what you're going to do. I was upset when I found out how vtiger user privileges works with files. But know I how sophisticated it is. I shared my info as a comment.

Comment: Another matter to say (maybe obvious): user privileges on this triggers after installation: 1- creating user 2- changing a role or profile or anything that changes a user privilege. If your development works on a specific privilege that doesn't change, don't worry, copy existing privileges and go on.

Comment: From memory, you can delete the /user_privileges files and they will be recreated when you log in. It is like a cache to reduce the DB load.

Answer (score 0):

Choice 1 is appropriate. VC must always track the *source* code, not the products of any interpreter or processing. I feel your pain. It is so easy to tweak that Vtiger source code, and VC tends to be left by the wayside.

Answer (score 0):

Get familiar with [GIT](http://www.git-scm.com/). Really, it is what you want. Look [here](https://github.com/SteffenKockel/vtiger), I already did it.

1. Copy the *original* code in one branch
2. Copy the modified code into another branch
3. Make a diff or better, run `git format-patch`
4. Install (checkout) your new Version
5. Check the patches and apply them, if necessary.

Bonusses

1. Have a private and a public remote for your repo, so that you can keep track on the crumpy files in `user_privileges` and friends in private, but share code with others
2. Have an absolutely beautiful backup with daily rollback by just setting up a branch, a remote and a cronjob.
3. Beeing able to replicate the live situation within minutes for local development
4. Painfree Updates !!

I know, this is no easy task, but once done, it will make your live pretty much easier.